# Google Maps API v3, can't call method "panTo" of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just want to move the marker on the map, and have declared the variable `map`, `marker` as global, but I'm not able to use it in the function `moveMarker()`.  I'm new to JavaScript, so this problem may be simple but I still can't solve it - can anybody help me to fix it?

```
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 50),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    setTimeout("moveMarker(1)", 2000);
}

function moveMarker(i) {
    //delayed so you can see it move
    if (i > 10) {
        return;
    }
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50 + 0.1 * i, 50 + 0.1 * i);
    marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
    map.panTo(myLatLng);
    var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    newlatlng = latlng.toString();
    marker.setTitle(newlatlng);
    setTimeout("moveMarker(" + (i + 1) + ")", 1500);
}

window.onload = function () {
    // Setup the dnd listeners.
    initialize();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do replace your "," with ";", otherwise it thinks you are re-defining variable "map":

```
            var map;
        var marker;

        function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 50);
            myOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            setTimeout("moveMarker(1)", 2000);
        }

        function moveMarker(i) {
            //delayed so you can see it move
            if (i > 10) {
                return;
            }
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50 + 0.1 * i, 50 + 0.1 * i);
            marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
            map.panTo(myLatLng);
            var latlng = marker.getPosition();
            newlatlng = latlng.toString();
            marker.setTitle(newlatlng);
            setTimeout("moveMarker(" + (i + 1) + ")", 1500);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            // Setup the dnd listeners.
            initialize();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Google Map's **`PanTo`** method.  The reason for the problem is your **`myLatLng`** variable.

So change the scope of to **`myLatLng`** variable to **`Global`**, problem will be solved.

Check this [**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2824/)

Comment: Actually myLatLng doesn't need to be global, it is only used within the scope of the function. There is no need to define variables as global unless you need them.